# Troubleshooting Magento Contact Form

Tags: php, magento

Our contact form has stopped working, and I"m not sure what the problem is. I can confirm that other e-mails are working correctly. The weird part is that once I click submit, it returns me to `http://mydomain.com/contact/index/` and has no message. Also, if the test message looks spammy, **Akismet** will catch it in the Akimet section. Here is my setup:

**Page with form:**

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post/" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

The **form.html** code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction();?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
<div class="fieldset">
    <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="wide">
            <label for="reason" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Reason') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <textarea name="reason" id="reason" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Reason') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="buttons-set">
    <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Here are the contents of system.log:

```
2012-08-10T18:21:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: comment  in /var/www/html/svn/magento/website/trunk/app/code/community/Centerax/Akismet/Model/Api.php on line 56
2012-08-10T18:21:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: comment  in /var/www/html/svn/magento/website/trunk/app/code/community/Centerax/Akismet/controllers/Contacts/IndexController.php on line 52
```

Comment: Anything in your system.log, exception.log or PHP error logs?

Comment: Added system.log contents to original post.

Comment: Have you reindexed and cleared the cache?

Comment: All indexes are up to date and cache disabled (dev server).

Comment: Maybe post up relevant portions from the community extension controller and model - not sure if they are free or readily available but I don't have them on hand here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed. At some point I changed the default field of 'comment' to 'reason' as you can see in my code above. Akismet was throwing an error because it couldnt find 'comment' to check for spam. Thanks anyways everyone.

Comment: This also is standard behavior for the contacts controller in a stock Magento install. All the forms fields in **form.phtml** that are **required** must exist and be as named in the original installed base template. In addition to the javascript validation that highlights required fields with missing content, the contacts controller checks for empty required fields, proper email address existing in the email field and that the hideit field has not had a value set. To change this, you will need to create a module to do a controller overwrite to change the above logic.